# Scala Process not closing properly

Tags: multithreading, scala, process

I have a pattern to start an external program and if it does not finish in time, kill it:

```
    val process = command.run(false)
    val future = Future(blocking {
      process.exitValue()
    })
    val ret = try {
      Await.result(future,
                   duration.Duration(TIME, duration.SECONDS))
    } catch {
      case _: TimeoutException =>
        process.destroy()
    }
```

However, something goes wrong and the processes (or threads?) keep piling up. When I start I have around 70 threads (according to the `Thread.getAllStackTraces.keySet().size`). After running for a couple hours I have over 310 and the application crashes as all memory is used up.

A listing of the threads looks like this:

```
3  finalizer  waiting
173  scala-execution-context-global-173  waiting
555  scala-execution-context-global-555  waiting
762  scala-execution-context-global-762  waiting
1278  process reaper  blocked
1280  simple-error-spawn-thread-760  runnable
1651  simple-output-spawn-thread-943  runnable
636  scala-execution-context-global-636  waiting
86  process reaper  blocked
153  scala-execution-context-global-153  waiting
1593  simple-output-spawn-thread-913  runnable
588  scala-execution-context-global-588  waiting
769  scala-execution-context-global-769  waiting
1500  simple-output-spawn-thread-871  runnable
352  scala-execution-context-global-352  waiting
1245  simple-output-spawn-thread-743  runnable
1793  simple-error-spawn-thread-1012  runnable
1586  simple-error-spawn-thread-910  runnable
1801  process reaper  runnable
1666  process reaper  blocked
395  scala-execution-context-global-395  waiting
1203  simple-output-spawn-thread-721  runnable
...
```

I call this code segment from within threads the execution context of the future is `global`. The started processes are JVM processes and have a maximum allowed memory size of 20G, the docker container has 480G. As I guarantee to not call this code segment more than 20 times concurrently I should at any point in time have 80G to spare, but this is clearly not the case.

**How can I ensure that a started process is really closed including all the associated memory?**

Comment: `As I guarantee to not call this code segment more than 20 times concurrently ` -- evidently you _do not_ guarantee that, because `When I start I have around 70 threads ... After running for a couple hours I have over 310`

Comment: yes you are somewhat right, my assumed guarantee seems to be broken. However, I start 20 threads running the code and the above snippet should be blocking, i.e., cannot continue until the process is either killed or finishes successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reduce the amount of threads by changing

```
val process = preped.run(true)
```

to

```
val process = preped.run(new ProcessIO(_.close(),_.close(),_.close()))
```

I now have only 178 threads and it does not increase further. Still surprisingly large, though.

*Any answer that addresses/explains this large amount of threads will get accepted instead of this one*